# Transform SQL into LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have this sql query :

```
SELECT
      Count(Distinct([AgenziaCompleta])) as Age
      ,Count(Distinct([Corso])) as NumCorsi
      ,[PV_Prov]
  FROM [SvilDB].[dbo].[V_PreiscrittiSistemiCorsiFiniti_ConRegPvCom]
  WHERE [SvilDB].[dbo].[V_PreiscrittiSistemiCorsiFiniti_ConRegPvCom].[PV_Reg] = N'XXXXXX'
  GROUP BY [PV_Prov]
```

How can I turn it into linq?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Have you tried [breaking the problem into smaller pieces](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/)?

Comment: I have a list of objects that populate a gridview and I populate a new gridview filtered. 
I take the filter by a dropdownlist 

I can not do a database query because the query is about 1000000 rows ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim table = V_PreiscrittiSistemiCorsiFiniti_ConRegPvCom

Dim q = table.Where(Function(x) x.PV_Prov = N'XXXXXX')
             .GroupBy(Function(x) x.PV_Prov)
             .Select(Function(Grp) New With {.Age = Grp.Select(Function(x) x.AgenziaCompleta).Distinct().Count(),
                                             .NumCorsi = Grp.Select(Function(x) x.Corso).Distinct().Count() })
```

but because you filtering for single PV Prov value, you can simply:

```
Dim q = table.Where(Function(x) x.PV_Prov = N'XXXXXX')

Dim Age      = q.Select(Function(x) x.AgenziaCompleta).Distinct().Count()
Dim NumCorsi = q.Select(Function(x) x.Corso)          .Distinct().Count()
```

Comment: I have a list of objects that populate a gridview and I populate a new gridview filtered. 
I I can not do a database query 


Dim filter As String = DdlScegliregione.SelectedValue

GdrProvincia.DataSource = listCorsiFiniti.Where(Function(x) x.Provincia = filter)
                          .GroupBy(Function(x) x.Provincia)
                           .Select(Function(Grp) New With 
                           {.Age = Grp.Distinct(Function(x)x.AgenziaCompleta).Count(),
                              .NumCorsi = Grp.Distinct(Function(x) x.Corso).Count()})

 GdrProvincia.DataBind()

Comment: Is an error... but i can't write the error because i have a VisulStudio in Italian when I write .SELECT the visualStudio gives me the error

Comment: No matter that it's Italian, paste the error message.

Comment: Metodo di estensione 'Public Function Select(Of TResult)(selector As System.Func(Of System.Linq.IGrouping(Of String, Corsi), Integer, TResult)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TResult)' definito in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': La funzione annidata non ha una firma compatibile con il delegato 'System.Func(Of System.Linq.IGrouping(Of String, Corsi), Integer, TResult)'.

Comment: I found another solution but it'sn't very "elegant" like your. From lc In listCorsiFiniti
        '                          Where lc.Regione = DdlScegliregione.SelectedValue
        '                          Group lc By key = lc.Provincia Into Group
        '                          Select Provincia = key, NumeroCorsi = Group.Count(),
        '                          NumeroAgenzie = (From lc In listCorsiFiniti Where (lc.Regione = DdlScegliregione.SelectedValue And lc.Provincia = key)
        '                                 Group By lc.Agenzia Into g = Group Select g).Distinct.Count()